# How to read old Enqueued messages from ActiveMQ Topic with Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I have Apache Camel client(consumer) which listen messages from remote ActiveMQ Topic, I observed it only read messages when Consumer is running.

if consumer is not listening and producer send messages they get enqueued forever and picked by consumer.

I want that my Client should read all en-queued messages when its up

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ActiveMQComponent amq = new ActiveMQComponent();
        amq.setConnectionFactory( new ActiveMQConnectionFactory() );
        amq.setUsername("admin");
        amq.setPassword("admin");
        amq.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:8161");

        Main main = new Main();
        main.bind("activemq", amq);
        main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouter());
        main.run(args);
    }
```

Following is router code

```
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        from("activemq:topic:saadtopic")
        .transform(simple(" ${body}"))
        .to("stream:out");
    }
```

**ActiveMQ=5.15.9
ApacheCamel=2.24.1**

[image]

Comment: You need to be [durable subscriber](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html). See `subscriptionDurable` [option](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-activemq/src/main/docs/activemq-component.adoc)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using durable subscriptions and you send a message to a topic that has no subscribers the message is essentially dropped never to be seen again.  The broker only stores Topic messages when there is a durable subscription with an offline subscriber and the message is marked as persistent.

If you want the have access to messages sent when consumers are down then you need to ensure that those consumers have run at least once and created a durable topic subscriptions.